# Kivy: How to attach a callback to a widget created in kvlang

Tags: python, kivy

When you want to attach a callback to a kivywidget, for example a textinput you can use the bind() function. Example from [Kivy docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#usage-example) for a textinput:

```
def on_text(instance, value):
    print('The widget', instance, 'have:', value)

textinput = TextInput()
textinput.bind(text=on_text)
```

But how do I attach it to an element that was created in the kvlang file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `bind()` on the widget referenced by `self.ids['id_from_kvlang']`. However this cannot be done on class level, you need to operate on the instance. So you need to put it in a function of the class.

The `__init__` function is called at the instantiation of the object so you can put it there. However you need to schedule it, so it won't happen instantly, the widgets you are binding to are not there yet so you have to wait a frame.

```
class SomeScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        #execute the normal __init__ from the parent
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        #the callback function that will be used
        def on_text(instance, value):
            print('The widget', instance, 'have:', value)

        #wrap the binding in a function to be able to schedule it
        def bind_to_text_event(*args):
            self.ids['id_from_kvlang'].bind(text=update_price)

        #now schedule the binding
        Clock.schedule_once(bind_to_text_event)
```

Answer (score 2):

Get a reference to the element, then call `bind` as normal. For instance, for the root widget of the application you can use `App.get_running_app().root.bind`, or for others you can navigate the widget tree via kv ids.

Comment: When I call `self.ids['id_from_kvlang'].bind(text=on_text)` on the class level I get `NameError: name 'self' is not defined` which I can understand, but I don't know how to do it correctly. Without `self.` I get `NameError: name 'ids' is not defined` Or shouldn't I call it from class level?

Comment: Don't call it from class level - this is the class definition, but you're trying to interact with an instance of the class.

Comment: Ah ok, so I have put it in the __init__ function, but then you also need to put a small delay on it because the widgets don't exist yet on the first moment. I will rewrite the example from the docs in a new answer for future reference. Thanks for you help!