# Kivy Widget ids access in __init__

Tags: python, kivy

I have a simple custom widget defined in kv file:

```
<CustomWidget>:
    TextInput:
        id: text_input
```

And a class implementing it:

```
class CustomWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ids['text_input'].bind(insert_text=numeric_filter)
```

This code fails, because `self.ids` is not populated at the point I'm trying to use it. Is there some callback or function of `kivy.uix.Widget` which I can override to perform first time setup my widgets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Clock.schedule_once(..., 0)`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html) to schedule the call to a function relying on `ids` Having been built:

```
class CustomWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.init_ui, 0)
    def init_ui(self, dt=0):
        self.ids['text_input'].bind(insert_text=numeric_filter)
```

Comment: Ok, this seems to be the best option. Same thing was suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/a/35430569/1008902

Comment: @DikobrAz and actually I think the question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/26916262/1893154

Comment: @zeeMokeez right, but that question is so long... and I didn't find it when looking for my problem. Let community or moderator decide whether to remove this question or not.

Comment: @DikobrAz actually I think this question is better (more concise). So I don't think it should be deleted.